# Google Calendar API with next.js app router

Tags: next.js, google-api, app-router

I am trying to create an api route to fetch a google calendar using the google calendar api but whatever i do i get the internal server error.

I have created a route.js file within api/calendar folder in my app folder, i also have a client component that fetches the from the route.js, the routing works since when i just put a simple string response it is logged in the console. I also use another component to fetch the need credentials for google.

Here is the route.js:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";
import loadSavedCredentialsIfExist from '@/app/credentials';

export async function GET (){

    const auth = loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    const result = calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: 'primary',
            timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
            maxResults: 10,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: 'startTime',
          });
    const events = result.data.items || [];
    const json = {
        events
    };
    
    return NextResponse.json(json);
}
```

and here is the request to the api:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/calendar').then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))}, [])
```

and the credential helper file:

```
export default async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
    const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');
    try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    
    const { client_id, client_secret, refresh_token } = credentials;
    
    const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret);
    auth.setCredentials({ refresh_token });
  
    if (auth.isTokenExpiring()) {
      const { credentials } = await auth.refreshAccessToken();
      auth.setCredentials(credentials);
    }
  
    return auth;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading credentials:', error);
    return null;
  }
  }
```